# Click-To-Call issues with new VOIP

Tags: crm, voip

We recently switched over from vocalocity/vonage to Nextiva. The only problem we are having is with click to call.

We have a web GUI where we have the customer's name and Restaurant name, those links open vocalocity's application for click-to-call.

The problem with Nextiva is like skype it only looks for phone numbers that are displayed and turns them INTO links. But we cannot display the numbers without cluttering the screen.

I tried turning it into a tel:888-888-8888 link but I cannot select Nextiva to handle the TEL: Protocol. I am using "Broadsoft Xtended Dialer" addon for google chrome with Nextiva's Application, cannot figure out how to get either to accept a link version.

tel: does not work because I cannot select Nextiva to handle the protocol
nextiva: the app does not recognize this command

Is there ANY possible work around anyone can think of? This is for the company I work at, pretty important and know you guys would know.

Comment: Usually I get answers pretty fast but it looks like no one know's how to answer this on? Basically I need the VOIP Nextiva App or Broadsoft xtended dialer to take a "link" instead of just "turning formatted numbers into links to click" Basically we just can't display the phone number visually for it to pick it up.

Comment: Ok how is this, I will pay anyone 25$ for a quick answer. Respond to this post, if you know how to solve the issue and I will provide my number for you to call, and will pay you via pay pal or a method of your choosing.

Comment: Just no hope here huh...

Comment: too little too late, but try "sip:888-888-8888"

Comment: Unfortunately, @DuaneLortie's response is correct. Nextiva doesn't handle tel: links properly and needs sip: instead. This seems to be the case with any softphone used on their network including Nextiva, Bria/X-Lite, and Jitsi.

Comment: If this is on windows systems, I've had success defining my own protocol handler by create a registry entry it. For chrome I used "Tel Linker" plugin that lets you set what protocol to prefix # with   Google "custom protocol handler"

Answer (score 0):

2 possible solutions, but the easiest is to switch to a Google Chrome extension called "Tell Linker"   By default it will prepend `tel:` to phone numbers, but you can change that in options, it would look like this in the options dialog.

`sip:(1)(2)(3)`

2nd option, assuming these are windows clients, is create a .reg file containing a protocol handler entry for tel:  You could likely export the `sip` handler, edit it, swap all `sip` for `tel` and merge the new entry.